# How to show different favicon depending on domain

Tags: asp.net, iis, umbraco

I am building a website that can be accessed from *domain1.com* and *domain2.com*.

So *domain1.com* and *domain2.com* will show the exact same content, except:

- Logo image
  No problem, this is how I do it:

  `<%= Request.ServerVariables["SERVER_NAME"].Contains("domain1") ? "domain1.jpg" : "domain2.jpg" %>`
- Favicon (How do I do this??? I can only put 1 favicon.ico in the root folder)

So I have 2 favicons (domain1.ico and domain2.ico)
How do I show domain1.ico for *domain1.com* and domain2.ico for *domain2.com*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define where the favicon is located from a tag within the `<head></head>` tag.

```
<link rel="icon" href="Path-To/specialFavicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
```

And then create some code that generates the path for the favicon